# How to setup a line length marker in vim/gvim?

Tags: vim, gvim

Some GUI text editors have a vertical line which serves as line length marker (it helps keeping lines shorter than 80 chars in source code files).

Is is possible to have something similar in vim/gvim? I know about **ruler** vim option, but it is not very handy to follow it visually on a big screen.

Edit: when googling for "colorcolumn" to learn more, I have found that this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns

Comment: duplicate on another site... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Just execute this

```
:set colorcolumn=72
```

You can also prefix the argument with `-` or `+` to put the marker that many columns to the left or right of [`textwidth`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27textwidth%27), and it accepts a comma-separated list of columns. I think the [`colorcolumn`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27colorcolumn%27) option is only in Vim 7.3. See

```
:help colorcolumn
```

Comment: Wow, vim never ceases to amaze me!

Comment: Nice! Also useful when `columns=80`, `wrap` is set and `colorcolumn=81,161,241,321,401,481,561,641,721,801` – shows up to 10 wrapped lines with the first column highlighted.

Comment: To unset, run `set colorcolumn=` or `set cc=`

Comment: to set the marker line color, run `:highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=grey`, run `:help ctermbg` to see the color list

Answer (score 32):

From Damian Conway's ["More Instantly Better Vim" talk](http://youtu.be/aHm36-na4-4) at OSCON 2013:

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=magenta
call matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v', 100)
```

This results in the character being highlighted in magenta (the screenshot is in `DarkCyan`) when the line goes over the 80-character maximum.

[image: vim with highlighting enabled]

For gVim: it's best to [move those 2 lines to the last part](https://superuser.com/a/771578/2132) of your `.vimrc` file to ensure it works.

Comment: Huh!  I just answered your __very__ similar question about this... small world!  http://superuser.com/questions/771558/line-length-highlighting-works-in-console-vim-not-gui

Comment: I put this answer in, then remembered I couldn't do it in gVim, so I asked. ;)

Comment: Wow, this is really great! This is the kind of feature I wouldn't even know to look for. I'm using the pattern `'\$81v\S'` which matches only non-whitespace characters. This means the highlight will not show when the line is exactly 80 characters long (which is something that really bothered me). See this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985042/vim-search-for-lines-with-or-without-character-in-specific-column

Comment: Want to make a couple of corrections to my previous comment. The `$` should have been a `%`. Likewise, I now use the pattern `\%81v.` since this ensures the 81st column will be highlighted for any character in the 81st column, which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
grep '.\{81\}' file
```

or

```
set colorcolumn=80
```

(or the shorthand equivalent)

```
set cc=80
```

or as aforementioned:

```
match ErrorMsg '\%>80v.\+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a clumsy trick from [Hacking Vim: A Cookbook to get the Most out of the Latest Vim Editor](http://www.packtpub.com/hacking-vim-cookbook-get-most-out-latest-vim-editor/book)  by Kim Schultz.

It highlights with `ErrorMsg` (usually bright red) any lines that go over 80 characters. Works well for me.

```
function! RemoveWidthLimitWarnigns()
    silent! call matchdelete(4)
endfunction
function! InsertWidthLimitWarnings()
    call RemoveWidthLimitWarnigns()
    call matchadd("ErrorMsg", "\\%>79v.\\+", 10, 4)
endfunction
```

Comment: What am I supposed to do with this snippet? Just stick it into .vimrc?

Comment: Trying first by just calling `:call matchadd("ErrorMsg", "\\%>79v.\\+", 10, 4)` suffices. But I wouldn't recommend this anymore since @garyjohn knew something better